#  PHPExcel formatting

Tags: php, formatting, switch-statement, phpexcel

I need some help regarding PHPExcel, we have a script that inputs logs of our web-application such as searches, keywords, etc into an excel file. I want the script to display the logs in a such a way that few parameters are Black, few in green. Here si the part of the script that I need to modify:

```
$data = parse_command($log_command, $content);
$command = $data['command'];

            $params = $data['params'];

            if ($command == 'skip')
                continue;

            $curr_row++;

            if ($save_to_excel)
            {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$curr_row.':C'.$curr_row)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$curr_row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_XLSX15);
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A'.$curr_row, $request_time)
                    ->setCellValue('B'.$curr_row, $command)
                    ->setCellValue('C'.$curr_row, $params);

            }
```

The excel file has logs that contains dates, type of searches, keywords. so I want few types of searches in Black such as Venue searches in black, event searches in Blue, I hope I am clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have u tried to look out in phpexcel forum? They have provide plenty of solution for setting colors? Even they have provided good examples with download in documents folder.

Comment: @kamal, dude I went through all the solutions in the forum and and sleo read the documentation, it isn working out for me for reasons unknown. May be it has to do with the other parts of the code.

Answer (score 6):

To set the text color through phpexcel you could use:

```
$sheet->getStyle("A".$cur_row)->getFont()->getColor()->applyFromArray(array("rgb" => $color))
```

Chose the color depending on your keywords. Phpexcel also supports conditional formatting, its described in section 4.6.23 of the "developer documentation" contained in the download package.

Usage:

Assuming you want to color the second column based on its content:

```
$color = "000000";
switch ($command) {
     case "keyword_yellow" : $color = "FFA500"; break;
     case "keyword_red" : $color = "FF0000"; break;
     case "keyword_green" : $color = "008000"; break;
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("B".$cur_row)->getFont()->getColor()->applyFromArray(array("rgb" => $color))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I looked into Conditional formatting but requirement is that I have to use 'switch' to make it work. And could you please elaborate how would I use the above two lines with my keyowrds, forgive me for ignorance, I am a beginner in PHP.

Comment: Thanks so much, will try this and will get back to you, really appreciate the help.

Comment: switch($command) {
case 'venue search':$color= '000000'; break;
case 'event print':
$color = '006400';break;
case 'Concierge event list:  $color = '556B2F'; break;

default:
$color = '556B2F';
break;  
Now the problem I am having is that few cells are highlighted in green as I used default as green and not all venue searches are not in green, only a few and rest of the cases such as event print or event list are just in black. Been trying to figure out but couldn't find any solution and also tried conditional formatting and didint find any luck. Can you please help me again with this?

Comment: I provided not only the general idea on how this can be done, but also a code snippet adapted to your setup. I can`t do the debugging for you, even if you would provide more details. You need to check the keywords and the content of the cells and figure it out from there. Fell free to ask another question, if you could identify the problem and need some more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$linha.':I'.$linha.'')->getFont()->getColor()->applyFromArray(array("rgb" => '$color'));`

Then Set value `$color`.